# Not able to redirect to recod detail page after Vf page download as CSV on Button Aura type

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"></aura:attribute>
</aura:component>
```

```
({
  doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    var conId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      url: "/apex/pocForCSVDownloader?id=" + conId
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
   
  }
});
```

```
<apex:page controller="PocForCSVDownloaderController" contentType="text/csv#file.csv" action="{!generatePDF}">
  {!csvString}
</apex:page>
```

```
public with sharing class PocForCSVDownloaderController {
  public static string contactId;
  public static string csvString { get; set; }
  public static PageReference generatePDF() {
    contactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    system.debug('=====contcatId====' + contactId);

    csvString = 'Ramesh, Yadav';
    return invokeDetailPage();
  }

  public static PageReference invokeDetailPage() {
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(
      'https://raptbot-ramesh-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Contact/' +
        contactId +
        '/view'
    );
    Aura.redirect(pageRef);
    system.debug('====invoke to return page===');
    return pageRef;
    
  }
}
```

Comment: A single sentence and a code dump isn't really enough for us to understand what your issue is. Since we can't read your mind or see your screen, you need to [edit] your question to include enough details for other people to be able to understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks for guidance

Answer (score 0):

A file download cannot both provide file content and redirect to a new location. This is a limitation of HTTP itself.

Instead, create a link, add it to the page's body, and use the click method to download the file.

That would look something like the following code.

```js
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "file.csv";
a.href = `/apex/pocForCSVDownloader?id=${conId}`;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
Promise.resolve().then(
  $A.getCallback(() => {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      url: `/${conId}`
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
  }));
```